# Angularjs -Updating individual values in ng-repeat from outside its scope using "this" keyword

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, this

I am trying to update quantity number of individual items in a table whenever the user clicks the item in another table.

For example, I have list of all items in **Table A**

```
                <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
                        <td>{{item.fid}}</td>
                        <td{{ item.fname }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.calorie }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.protein }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.carb }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.fat }}</td>
                        <td><button ng-click=additem(values)>Add</button>
               <tr>
```

Now when the user clicks this Add button, the selected item gets added to another table (Table B).
I have disabled duplicates in Table B and want that if the user is repeatedly adding same item then the quantity of the item in Table B should increase.

**Table B**

```
                      <tr ng-repeat="sitem in sitems>
                        <td>{{sitem.fname}}</td>
                        <td>{{sitem.calorie}}</td>
                        <td>{{sitem.protein}}</td>
                        <td>{{sitem.carb}}</td>
                        <td>{{sitem.fat}}</td>
                        <td>*</td>
                        <td><button ng-click="removeItem(values)">Remove</button></td>
                    </tr>
```

- is the one where i want the increased quantity to be shown.

I have tried using "this" keyword but didn't worked, I am new to angular so i don't know what all are my options and got mixed up.

Comment: By using some unique property!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep track of two separate array to accomplish this.

This is the code snippet: `

```
$scope.additem = function(item) {
        var index = $scope.sitems.indexOf(item);
        if (index === -1) {
        item.quantity = 1;
        $scope.sitems.push(item);
        return;
      } 
        item.quantity++;
        $scope.sitems[index] = item;

    };
```

`

Complete Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nbakliwal18/4kbo7Lfo/2/

Also you check for quantity before adding.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass item to the function addItem() :

```
<td><button ng-click=addItem(item)>Add</button>
```

and push this item to your array sitems in your function :

```
$scope.addItem = function(item) {
    $scope.sitems.push(item);
}
```

A workaround for the duplicates in ng-repeat is to add `track by $index` to it :

```
<tr ng-repeat="sitem in sitems track by $index">
```

**Update 1:**

Updated my answer with working example in [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FyUmG4c3NZYXhIUAJ2mB?p=preview)

**Update 2:**

Here is an example with lodash for quantity [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/eFW1w6RU5q5RrKaWIo4y?p=preview)

Comment: Yes i am doing that, thing is every time when the same item is pushed, i want its quantity to be increased in Table 2

Comment: ah I see, thats because ng-repeat does not allow duplicates. you can however add an extra check in the function to check if the item exists, if it does, then add +1 to the quantity. Do you have a quantity attribute?

Comment: No, not in Table A, Actually the values coming in Table A are from database. Will i have to make a "quantity" attribute in table B's sitems? And then create a check function? Will it work for every item individually?

Comment: Well it really depends on what you want to do with the second array. Do you want it to contain all items or do you want it to only contain unique items with a quantity?

Comment: I want the second array to contain only unique items whos quantity increase when the user clicks on same item in table 1

Comment: In that case I suggest you to use [lodash.js](https://lodash.com/) see [documentation](https://lodash.com/docs) and use the `_.includes` to check if the item exists in your second table. You will need an attribute quantity in your second table.

Comment: I have uploaded a working example with lodash to help you out :) [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/eFW1w6RU5q5RrKaWIo4y?p=preview)